# Parse as type json in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Postgres, I can parse json using the following:

```
select
        *
    from
        (
            select
                json_array_elements(serialized_data :: json) -> 'fields' ->> 'rent_amount' as rent_amount,
                json_array_elements(serialized_data :: json) ->> 'model' as model,
                json_array_elements(serialized_data :: json) ->> 'pk' as listing_id,
                *
            from
                public.field_history_fieldhistory
            where
                field_name = 'rent_amount' -- limit 30
        ) x
    where
        model = 'listings.listing'
    order by
        listing_id,
        date_created
```

However, I need to shift this query to Redshift, and I now get the error `type "json" does not exist` .

How would I accomplish this in Redshift? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Redshift so directly.

In Redshift you store your JSON data as VARCHAR and then you can query it using [`json_extract_path_text()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) and/or [`json_extract_array_element_text()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html).

Alternatively you can parse JSON using [`JSON_PARSE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_PARSE.html) into a `SUPER` type which allows operations similar to the ones in your question.